# Html encoding with RazorGenerator.Templating

Tags: c#, security, html-encode, razor-2, razorgenerator

I am using `RazorGenerator.Templating` `v2.3.11` for email templates. And `Razor Generator` plugin `v1.9.1` - utilizing the `TemplateTransformer`. 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorGenerator.Templating

I use this to create Email templates which then generates emails on demands given user and system content. I need to html encode the user content.

I've discovered that unlike MVC Razor views, the `TemplateTransformer` does not automatically encode user content. This is obviously a **massive** security issue, since I'm sending out non-sanitized content via email.

What is the best way to accomplish this, given that I am not referencing MVC, or System.Web, or anything like that?

Answer (score 0):

Because `RazorGenerator` does not seem to have a canned solution for encoding in the `TemplateTransformer`, and since the other transformers are only for if you are using MVC or WebForms:

I ended up just manually running `System.Net.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` on any content that could potentially be exploited. It was easy enough to do right in Razor.